# Redirect subdomains to their folders with htaccess for dynamic name of subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I have following structure in my root directory

```
/
/-site1
/-site2
.
.
.-site-n
```

I want to have **site1.example.com** to use **site1** folder, **site2.example.com** to use **site2** folder and so on. I want to achieve this with htaccess.I also want to redirect to 404 page if a directory (**sitex**) not exist. Please provide me suggestion to write **htaccess** file and also mention where should I need to put it.

Comment: Please show us, what you have already done in your .htaccess file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess rewrite subdomain to directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642426/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-directory)

Comment: I am using this: -
RewriteEngine On
Rewritemap lowercase int:tolowerRewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 !-d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -d
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
  ##RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
                RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

If this helps - tracing out the comments and from the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16161183/2478873)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%1/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ %1/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```